# The SystemInformation.FrameBorderSize return wrong size

Tags: .net, winforms, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I have found the strange issue in one of my projects. The exact reason of the issue is the fact that the [SystemInformation.FrameBorderSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.framebordersize.aspx) returns different values depends on whether the application running under debugger or not in VS2012.
I'm using the following test:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        this.label1.Text = SystemInformation.FrameBorderSize.ToString();
    }
}
```

Under debugger it return wrong size `(4,4)`, but not under debugger it return correct value `(8,8)`. The related WinAPI call ([GetSystemMetrics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) gets the same (incorrect) results.

**Update:**
We get incorrect result(4,4) when the project's Target Framework is set to ".Net Framework 3.5 Client Profile" and debugging. 
And we always get incorrect result (4,4) when the Target Framework is ".Net Framework 4.5" either debugging or not.

Would someone provide me an information why does this may happens (this code works correctly under VS2010/VS2008/VS2005 at the same machine)? 
How can the VS2012 debugger or .Net Framework version affect the System Metrics at all?

Comment: I get `(4, 4)` in both scenarios.

Comment: @LarsTech: The correct value is (8,8). We get incorrect results when the project's Target Framework is set to ".Net Framework 3.5 Client Profile". And we always get (4,4) when the Target Framework is "".Net Framework 4.5".

Comment: The "Correct" value is whatever your theme has set. System I'm on is 5,5 and like Lars, I do not get different values under debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a related bug report on msconnect: [Regression: ::GetSystemMetrics delivers different values](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/753224/regression-getsystemmetrics-delivers-different-values) :

> This is due to the linker's minimum version being different in VS 2010
>   vs. VS 2012. The AppCompat shim is based on the minimum supported OS
>   defined by the linker rather than the _WIN_32_WINNT value used at app
>   compile time.

Another issues related to it:

1. [WinForm dialogs displayed differently by *.vshost.exe and *.exe using VS 2012 when FormBorderStyle set in form codebehind](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/759413/winform-dialogs-displayed-differently-by-vshost-exe-and-exe-using-vs-2012-when-formborderstyle-set-in-form-codebehind)
2. [The SystemInformation.FrameBorderSize property returns a wrong value if a debugger is attached](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/767777/the-systeminformation-framebordersize-property-returns-a-wrong-value-if-a-debugger-is-attached)

Unfortunatelly, all of these issues are **won't fix**.

Answer (score 0):

If you're building on an affected platform, check **Debugger.IsAttached** and if that returns **true**, double the values of **SystemInformation.FrameBorderSize**.

Like so:

```
public static Size RealFrameBorder {
  get {
    return new Size(
      SystemInformation.FrameBorderSize.Width * (Debugger.IsAttached ? 2 : 1),
      SystemInformation.FrameBorderSize.Height * (Debugger.IsAttached ? 2 : 1)
    );
  }
}
```

I know it's a hack. But it works. If you're on a platform that displays this *won't fix* issue.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid this is not a solution, because the result does not depend on debugger attached or not. You can see the details in my question/answer.